# Struggling in construction the tree hierarchy in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I wanted to use tree view but I am struggling in construction the tree (hierarchical view of information) in react.

same as https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_treeview.asp

What I am trying CodeSandBox - https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-babbage-9knrz?file=/index.js

JSON - (this is not fixed can be any format)

```
const data = [
  {
    title: "Node 1",
    childNodes: [
      { title: "Childnode 1.1" },
      {
        title: "Childnode 1.2",
        childNodes: [
          {
            title: "Childnode 1.2.1",
            childNodes: [{ title: "Childnode 1.2.1.1" }]
          },
          { title: "Childnode 1.2.2" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I have toggle function which expand and vice versa the tree node.
I am struggling in construction the tree in react.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The first of all you don't need use `<Tree/>` as the recursive component, instead of it use `<Node/>`

The second thing in React you don't need to use the `querySelector` and `classList` for changing `state` of a component.

I've implemented my idea in code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-fire-xjvhl?file=/index.js)

```
const Tree = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(({ title, childNodes }) => (
        <Node key={title} title={title} childNodes={childNodes} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

class Node extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false
  };
  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { title, childNodes } = this.props;
    const { isOpen } = this.state;

    return (
      <li>
        <span className="caret" onClick={this.toggle}>
          {title}
        </span>
        {childNodes && isOpen && (
          <ul>
            {childNodes.map(({ title, childNodes }) => (
              <Node key={title} title={title} childNodes={childNodes} />
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default Tree
```

Comment: Thanks, 
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-babbage-9knrz?file=/index.js

I was trying to use caret-down in tooggle function when it's clicked, and one more thing is what if my json data in not fixed, and I have to get key value dynamically. Thanks..